# Items per slide responsive

Tags: php, html, css

I've made a logo slider using Bootstrap (basically as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/juddlyon/Q2TYv/10/).

Within each slide there are 4 logos. I want to make this responsive, where on smaller screens it only shows 2 logos per slide. I'm not sure what the best way is to do this.

I can double the grid-4 width to 50% with media queries but then it will still show 4 per slide, in a 2x2 grid.

Another way is to duplicate the entire slide and hide and show the correct one, but this seems like a rather inefficient appreach.

So really I need to reduce the number of logos per slide as it is loaded.. but how?

I'm using WP and Advanced Custom Fields to populate the slider. Simplified code below:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $firstslide = 0;
    $slide = 0;
    $repeater = get_field('clients', $clients);
    $order = array();
    foreach( $repeater as $i => $row ) {
        $order[ $i ] = $row['name'];
    }

    array_multisort($order, SORT_ASC, $repeater);

    if($repeater):
        foreach($repeater as $i => $row):
            if ($firstslide == 0) {
                $class = "item active";
            } else {
                $class = "item";
            };

            if ($slide == 0) {
                echo '<div class="' . $class . '">';
            };
        ?>
            <div class="grid-4">
                <img src="<?php echo $row['logo']; ?>">
            </div>
        <?php
            if ($slide == 4) {
                echo '</div>';
                $slide = 0;
            } else {
                $slide++;
            }
            $firstslide++;
        endforeach; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
?>
```

This would results in something like:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo4.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo5.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo6.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo7.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo8.jpg"></div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo9.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo10.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo11.jpg"></div>
    <div class="grid-4"><img src="logo12.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Very simplified CSS for the grid:

```
.grid-4 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After more searching, it looks like Slick is a solution that will just take care this.

jsfiddle.net/BishopBarber/ufnjkjy4/1/